# I'm ..... having to pay yet another visit to the dentist

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

Which option fits best the following sentence.

> I'm ..... having to pay yet another visit to the dentist.
>
> 1.Dreading
>
> 2.Frightened
>
> 3.Terrified
>
> 4.Afraid

For me 4 sounds fitting better but other words suits to the sentence in meaning.

Comment: You might want to register and [merge](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your three (or more?) accounts so your accumulated rep (33 total at present) is all available to you.

Comment: While I don't think this is primarily opinion based (yes, it does indeed have only one answer that is grammatical), the quality of the question is still pretty low and I don't see much reason to re-open it. Pretty soon ELL is just going to be an answer key.

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, only "dreading" really fits *well*. It's an active participle, so it's more closely linked to the active nature of the rest of the sentence than the other three, which are all adjectives. It expresses the essential linkage between the feeling of dread and the reason for it more naturally than the others.

However, all are *possible*, and occasionally someone might want to use the odder forms for effect. To say you're "frightened going to the dentist" or similar means that you're effectively frightened *while* or *because of* or *during*. More common would be to insert "of" in there, for the perfectly ordinary "I'm *frightened of* having to pay yet another visit to the dentist." This makes it more specific and uses a much more common structure. However, that's not possible in your given exam question, and since I doubt they were attempting to test your rhetorical mastery of this type of ellipsis, the only possible answer is "**dreading**".

Answer (score 1):

> I'm dreading having to pay yet another visit to the dentist.

or

> I'm frightened of having to pay yet another visit to the dentist.

or

> I'm terrified of having to pay yet another visit to the dentist.

or

> I'm afraid of having to pay yet another visit to the dentist.

are all fine.

**To determine which one to use, you need context!**

The fourth choice has the softest tone of all four of them, and is used to keep the scare factor to a minimum.

The first one connotes that having to visit the dentist gives you the chills and that it is coming very soon. I would use it if I was either scared of dentists appointments so much, or that I **really** hate them.

The second one indicates that you're a bit scared of the appointment coming over.

Third one means that you're very scared of the the approaching appointment.

Comment: Note that "of" was apparently not provided in the question. It is therefore not available.

Comment: It was in general, not just in the examination.